# Is there a chart available displaying all Hebrew letters and vowels?

Tags: product-recommendation, hebrew, aleph-bet-letters

I'm looking for a nice chart that will give me the following things, so I can print it out and keep it handy:

- Picture of each letter in traditional "book" font = [image]
- Picture of each letter in handwritten block font = [image]
- Picture of each letter in handwritten cursive font = [image]
- Name of each letter in transliterated english = Aleph
- Numerical value of each letter = 1

Also, it would be wonderful if the chart featured the names and values for the nikudot (nikudot do have gematria, right?).

I can very readily read Hebrew, but I have problems remembering the names of the vowels as well as the order of the aleph-bet and each letter's numerical value. Is there something out there to help with this? I don't really need the pronunciation as much, as I can already read.

Answer (score 6):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_alphabet has all you want, though not all in one chart.

Vowels don't have *gimatriya* in any system I've heard of, though according to Alex's comment on this answer I'm not as knowledgeable as I might be.

Comment: Actually, they are assigned numerical values in some Kabbalistic writings. Basically, each dot is treated like a yud and assigned the value 10, and each line is treated like a vav and assigned the value 6. Thus, kamatz=16, sheva=20, and so forth.

Comment: @Alex So Shva and Tzeirei have the same value?

Comment: @DoubleAA, presumably: and _kubutz_ and _segol_.

Answer (score 5):

There are tons of charts [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=aleph%20beis%20chart&hl=en&biw=1024&bih=430&prmd=ivns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=ANEcTt3sOdLSgQe9j-3jCQ&ved=0CEEQsAQ), but none of them have every feature you want.

However, wikipedia does have all the information you're looking for, as answered [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8839/is-there-a-chart-available-displaying-all-hebrew-letters-and-vowels/8840#8840).

Why don't you make your own chart using the information on wikipedia? Use something like Excel or perhaps Google Documents and put all the information in the chart, just the way you want it.

Then you can share it online so that other people who are looking for the same kind of chart will be able to find one :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably do just that :) I was just wondering if I could save myself the trouble.

Answer (score 5):

Chinuch.org has what you are looking for @ http://chinuch.org/item_details.php?mid=8033&id=68&s=1 or
http://chinuch.org/home_topic_search.php?id=68&s=1